# Which countries or regions (EU, U.S., China, etc.) own the majority of debt when we include hidden debt in Africa?

Tags: international, africa

Which countries or regions (EU, U.S., China, etc.) own the majority of debt when we include hidden debt in Africa?

https://www.reuters.com/world/africa/african-states-private-debts-three-times-that-owed-china-2022-07-11/

> Chinese public and private lenders accounted for 12% of the
> continent's $696 billion external debts in 2020, while 35% was owed to
> other private creditors, according to an analysis of World Bank data
> by Debt Justice, a campaign group.

Reuters has different statistics compared to WP

https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2021/02/26/pandemic-has-worsened-africas-debt-crisis-china-other-countries-are-stepping/

> As Africa's largest bilateral creditor, China holds at least 21
> percent of African debt — and payments to China account for nearly 30
> percent of 2021's debt service, as shown in the figure below. Angola
> alone accounts for almost a third. [...]
>
> China also wrote off the accumulated arrears of at least 94
> interest-free loans amounting to at least $3.4 billion. However,
> interest-free loans make up less than 5 percent of China’s lending to
> Africa.

https://www.brookings.edu/blog/africa-in-focus/2019/07/10/figure-of-the-week-chinas-hidden-lending-in-africa/

There's mention of hidden debt, but I am guessing Western countries also have hidden debt, so how do you add them up to the equations and after doing so which countries own the most African debt?

Comment: The first report you cite is based on a study by Debt Justice which you can read [here](https://www.reuters.com/world/africa/african-states-private-debts-three-times-that-owed-china-2022-07-11/). Check the footnotes for sources. In particular the [World Bank has an online tool](https://databank.worldbank.org/source/international-debt-statistics) which provides incredibly detailed debt statistics, used by Debt Justice for their report.

Comment: @StuartF doesn't that just link to the Reuters article cited in the question?